# Is forget handling an exception a logic/runtime error or not an error

Tags: java, error-handling, runtime-error, logic-error

For example, read line from terminal by `BufferedReader` without handling the error

```
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try{            
        String input = input.readLine();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    // Do Noting
    }
```

Is not handling the IOException an error? if it is an error, is it an logical error or runtime error? And why?

Comment: Impossible to say.  It is an error if it does not match the intent of the programmer.  What is the intent of the programmer?

Comment: the intent is, it should handle a character, not a integer, if user input a integer, the program will have no way to handle it

Answer (score 0):

From the clarification in the comments, it is:

0. A language error

The `String input` masks access to the `BufferedReader input` - but maybe that's just an error in this posting

**and**

1. Several logical errors

The errors are (1) the impossibility of doing anything with successful input, since the variable goes out of scope, (2) the lack of feedback to the user about invalid input, and maybe (3) the lack of visible retry *or* program abort due to the error, one of which I'd guess should happen, and maybe (4) quietly eating all Exceptions when from the description it probably ought to handle IOException only, and (5) no code implemented for rejecting integers, as is claimed the requirements say - digits are characters too.

**and**

2. A runtime error

The failure of `readline` to read a line is an event that happens at run time, which may or may not occur on any given execution.

---

To say it differently, the logic error is failure to adequately anticipate and handle possible runtime errors.